# handling validation for element having name with obj.prop

Tags: angularjs, validation

Why validation does not work for elements for which name="Obj.prop" ? What are the alternatives to validate such element. I have an input element like this

```
<input required type="text" name="myObj.prop" ng-model="prop1" />
<label ng-show="createForm.myObj.prop.$error.required">Required</label>
```

The problem is that I must have name="myObj.prop" in order to pass correct value to server but if the name has a structure like this I cannot catch its $error. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using square bracket notation instead in your expression:

```
<label ng-show="createForm['myObj.prop'].$error.required">Required</label>
```